# close window and open a new window

Tags: javascript, html, window

what i'm trying to do is when the page loads it will
automatically close the window then opens a new window

here is the code i'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="prahma" content="no-cache">
<title>Auto Close and Open New window</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script language="javascript">
var url = "step5.php"
window.open(url,"","");
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
</script>

</head>
<body onload="closeIt();">
</body>
</html>
```

the window closes but does't open the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Open new window first then close the older one.